# Multi-level Latent Class Growth Curve Model of a double-repeated measures data structure

Tags: r, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, latent-class

I have an interesting data structure I'm trying to analyze. I've decided that the best route is most likely using some type of LCGA, but am having trouble conceptualizing the model. Unfortunately, I'm limited to using R and have been practicing with the OpenMX package.

The repeated measures data we are specifically trying to model as apart of the LCGA is below:

[image]

Where each session required participants to complete runs 1, 2, & 3. These same runs were completed in sessions 2 and 3. All of the variables collected remained consistent for each session.

While the sessions were inconsistently measured over time (e.g., teams could come back at any time), each run was separated by a consistent amount of time.

I'm having a difficult time finding any published articles that detail similar methods as we are using. Further, I'm having trouble conceptualizing this info in terms of OpenMX's code. Could anyone provide suggestions/resources that might set me in the right direction?

Thanks!